# Select name from combobox, find all the matching names in column E, then put all the the corresponding numbers from H into another combobox

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, activex

I have been searching for almost 2 days to find an answer to this and it is driving me insane. I am very new to VBA so I don't have any code to share, just been trying out things I find on other sites and youtube. I have a technician sign in sheet that I have been working on and these are the steps I need done:

1. select your name from the "Metrology Tech." combobox on the 'Metrology Tech log-in' sheet
2. VBA searches thru column H in 'metrology tracker' to find all matching names
3. The lot numbers from column E in 'metrology tracker' sheet are put into the "Lot Number" combobox if the value in column M in 'metrology tracker' sheet is equal to "Pend."

I've tried this [Create Dependent Combo Boxes on a Userform - Excel VBA](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3VTq_kyCJec) and it did not work it just returned all the values of the column I need and all the other articles and videos were pretty much the same thing.

one thing I should note is that most of the values in the metrology tracker are referenced from another file so the lot numbers are equal to a cell value in another file.

Edit:
Ive tried this even though I knew it wasn't going to work

```
Private Sub cboTech_change()

Select Case cboTech.Value
    Case Is = "employee 1"
        cboLotNum.RowSource = "LotNumber"
    Case Is = "employee 2"
        cboLotNum.RowSource = "LotNumber"
    Case Is = "employee 3"
        cboLotNum.RowSource = "LotNumber"
End Select
   
End Sub
```

and also tried this, but kept on gettting a "run-time error '424' object required"

```
Sub FndLot()

Dim idx As Long
Dim lngRow As Long
    
    idx = TechBox.ListIndex
    
    If idx <> -1 Then
        lngRow = TechBox.ListIndex
        Worksheets("Metrology Tracker").Range("E" & lngRow).Value = LotNum.Value
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Probably you need to split your question into two or maybe three. So what is the issue with point 1, regarding the login sheet? Do you already have the names in the combobox? What else than selecting their own name do the technicians need to do to log in? What do you plan to do with the selected login name? Are passwords involved.

Comment: @TomBrunberg The first step is taken care of, all of the names are referenced in cells k2:k11 and k1 is linked to the combobox so I have been referencing K1 as the name to search for. They need to select their name, enter in a lot number date, process, estimated finish date, est time. I would like to have the macro search a "assigned to" column in the metrology tracker sheet and return all the values associated with the name from the first combobox in the "lot number" coulmn and put those into the second combo box. So it would be a dependent combo box but all the examples have fixed lists

Comment: It's tough to explain because I am brand new at VBA. I hope I'm making some sense

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure what you want but this should get you started.

```vb
Private Sub cboTech_Change()

    Dim sName As String
    sName = cboTech.Text
    cboLotNum.Clear

    Dim ws As Worksheet, lastrow As Long, i As Long
    Set ws = Sheets("metrology tracker")
    With ws
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 1 To lastrow
            If .Cells(i, "H") = sName And .Cells(i, "M") = "pend" Then
               cboLotNum.AddItem .Cells(i, "E")
            End If
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```